# SharePoint list filter using dd-mm-yyyy format

Tags: javascript, rest, sharepoint-2013

I have been trying to fetch records that are created on a specific date eg. 18-09-2019

my url is : `https://dimensiondata3.sharepoint.com/_api/web/lists/getbytitle('PrathameshDemo')/items?$filter=Created eq datetime('13-09-2019')`

but i'm getting an error :

```
{
    "odata.error": {
        "code": "-1, Microsoft.SharePoint.SPException",
        "message": {
            "lang": "en-US",
            "value": "The query is not valid."
        }
    }
}
```

How to fetch this list for a specific date?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem was the formatting of string value as a valid SharePoint datetime.

SharePoint expects the date to be in ISO 8601 format.You could use the [toISOString()](https://www.w3schools.com/jsref/jsref_toisostring.asp) Method to get datetime with the ISO 8601 format.

For your requirements, you want to get the items created on the day 2019/09/13. Assuming you are using UTC standard time, modify the query as follows:

```
$filter=(Created ge datetime'2019-09-13T00:00:00Z')and (Created le datetime'2019-09-14T00:00:00Z')
```

Comment: Hi, is there any way to fetch List data without datetime, ie. with date only(19-09-2019)

Comment: In Sharepoint Rest api, the type of created column is datetime. You have to use datetime, to fetch list date with a date, you need to use a date range in the filter (2019-09-19 00:00:00-2019-09-20 00:00:00).

Comment: Okay thank you sir.also, can you help me with get document list url from document library(REST API), i am new to SP & its seems to be  very difficult for me to work on SP project.(how to fetch documents, move document from one folder to another etc). can you share any link that will be helpful

Comment: You could refer to this:https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sharepoint/dev/sp-add-ins/get-to-know-the-sharepoint-rest-service